# How do I transfer data over to the firebase database from my HTML/JS Program?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following code in my HTML program:

```
<label for="firstName">First name:</label>
<input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName"><br><br>
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="transferData(document.getElementById('firstName').value)"><br><br>
```

In my javascript file I have:

```
function transferData(firstName){
    transferName();
}

function transferName(){
    var firebaseRef= firebase.database().ref();
    var firstName= firstName.value;   
    firebaseRef.push().set(firstName);
}
```

The CDN from my firebase is in my HTML body tag. Other than that, from what I have see, I have everything I need for the transferData() method to transfer the first name to the realtime database. However, there is no data being transferred and there is only the one saying null.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you meant to pass `firstName` along to `transferName`, instead of passing no arguments:

```
function transferData(firstName){
    transferName(firstName);
}

function transferName(firstName){
    var firebaseRef= firebase.database().ref();
    var firstName= firstName.value;   
    firebaseRef.push().set(firstName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just tried it and it still does not work.